# USB-C Alt Mode display and Thunderbolt 3 simultaneously

Tags: display, thunderbolt, usb-c, hub

I have a laptop (2018 Lenovo 720 15") that has a single USB-C port. This single port is supposedly USB-C with Alt Mode video and also Thunderbolt 3.

Is it possible to use all of USB, video and Thunderbolt on the same port, via a hub? If so, is there a particular technical term, standard and/or keyword that I should use when searching for a compatible hub?

Background: I want to connect an external monitor, gigabit internet, a Thunderbolt studio audio interface and various USB peripherals to this laptop via a hub, without having to plug/unplug multiple cables. I also want hardware HDMI output, rather than software compressed video over USB (e.g. DisplayLink)

Thanks